# How to sort Multidimensional Array by (int) SubKeys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort a multidimensional array by sub-keys.

Example:

```
Array
(
    [Rep4] => Array
        (
            [key_location_id] => 49736
            [10] => Array
                (
                    [key_location_id] => 50265
                )

            [14] => Array
                (
                    [key_location_id] => 50275
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [key_location_id] => 50283
                )

            [16] => Array
                (
                    [key_location_id] => 50291
                )

            [26] => Array
                (
                    [key_location_id] => 50307
                )

            [22] => Array
                (
                    [key_location_id] => 50323
                )
        )
)
```

There are multiple top level arrays e.g.: Rep5, Rep6, etc., but I want to sort elements by key integer in the second level of the array. As you can see, now it's 10, 14, 12, 16, 26, 22, but I want them to be in ascending numerical order. However, "key_location_id" has to stay at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ksort` for each top level array

```
foreach ($yourArray as &$topLevelArray) {
    ksort($topLevelArray);
}
```

then view the output

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($yourArray,1).'</pre>';
```